# SQL server - restrict data entry based on subset of rows as foreign key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

In SQL server(2012) I have following table structures

**tableA**

```
id 
1
2
3
```

**tableB**

```
id 
1
2
3
```

**tableAB**

```
id Aid  Bid 
1   1   1 
2   1   2 
3   1   3 
4   2   1 
5   2   2 
6   2   3 
7   3   1
```

Can I create a tableC with columns as (id, abid) 
     - foreign key abid to table **ab**(id)

which can have data only for the abid corresponding to bid=2
i.e. my abid can only be 4,5 or 6

(because in table **ab** the bid for this keys is bid=2).

In other words I want to restrict the data in table **c** from the subset of rows in table **ab**

Comment: Thanks Ali, the question looks lot better now!